# ggplot scale_x_log10() with bigger base than 10 for the logarithm

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there an easy way to scale a ggplot by log base 20 or higher? This works great:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + geom_line() + scale_x_log10()
```

Unfortunately base 10 too small. There's a more general `scale_x_continuous` function that takes a `trans` argument, but there doesn't appear to be any log transforms higher than base 10.

Comment: You can make your own transformation object with `scales::trans_new()`. For example [Make a new scale in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52067545/make-a-new-scale-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a worked example of creating a new trans object to use in your plot:

**Initial plot**

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 10^(1:10))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_line()

p
```

[image]

**With log scale using base 100**

```r
p +  scale_y_continuous(trans = scales::trans_new(name = "log100",
                        transform = function(x) log(x, 100),
                        inverse = function(x) 100^x,
                        domain = c(1e-16, Inf)),
                        breaks = scales::breaks_log(5, 100),
                        labels = scales::comma)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you @Allan

Answer (score 3):

The `scales` package provides transforms to the `scale_x_continuous()` function. You can either use the built-in flexible log transform or create your own using the `trans_new()` function.

Built-in with base-20:

```
require(scales)
base=20
p1 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point()
p1 + scale_y_continuous(trans = scales::log_trans(base))
```

Make your own transform:

```
require(scales)
logTrans <- function(base=20){
  trans_new(name='logT',
          transform=function(y){
            return(log(y, base=base))
          },
          inverse=function(y){
            return(base^y)
          })
}

base=20
p1 + scale_y_p1 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point()
p1 + continuous(trans = logTrans(base=base))
```